# Assigning unique values to the index of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, buttonclick

I am trying to make my button take input from a textbox and add it to the index. The problem is that with everything I have tried, I cannot get it to give a unique value to each position in the index.

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[0] == 0)
        {
            nums[0] = int.Parse(inputText.Text);
            i++;
        }

        if (nums[1] == 0)
        {
            nums[1] = int.Parse(inputText.Text);
            i++;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(nums[i].ToString());
}
```

Right now my code inserts the value to both index positions instead of assigning a value to position 0 and then allowing the user to insert a different value into position 1 and so on and so on.

Comment: `int.Parse(inputText.Text)` is assigned to 0 and 1 of the array, so of course they are not different.  Did you mean to assign `i` to element 0?

Comment: If I understand what you want, you need a new field at the class level to keep track of the last index that was used. Then you could just do `nums[lastIndex] = ...; lastIndex++`. Or of course, use a `List<int>`.

Comment: Did you mean to use `else if (nums[1] == 0)` instead of `if` so both positions don't get updated at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what your intent is, but it looks like you might be trying to add numbers to an array. This code will assign the parsed string to the first item in the array that isn't zero.

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] == 0)
        {
            nums[i] = int.Parse(inputText.Text);
            break;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(nums[i].ToString());
}
```

But this would be a better way, because the user might type "0":

```
private int _lastUsedIndex = -1;
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var number = int.Parse(inputText.Text);

    //  Increment by one
    ++_lastUsedIndex;

    nums[_lastUsedIndex] = number;

    MessageBox.Show(number.ToString());
}
```

But still, arrays aren't a great idea: They can't grow as you add things. First they're bigger than you need, then suddenly they're too small and you crash. We have better options now. Unless your teacher insists that you must use an array, use `List<int>` instead. In this version, we'll also use a different way to parse the number, which won't crash if the user types "LOLWUT?!?!" instead of a number:

```
private List<int> nums = new List<int>();

private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number;

    if (int.TryParse(inputText.Text, out number))
    {
        nums.Add(number);

        MessageBox.Show(number.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(inputText.Text + " isn't a number, smart guy.");
    }
}
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g. THANK YOU!

Comment: This answer seems to cover the bases. BTW is your username a reference to [Lord Dunsany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Plunkett,_18th_Baron_of_Dunsany)?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks. Yes, it is.

Comment: One of my favorite authors :)

Comment: @p.s.w.g Mine too.

Comment: @BrandonLukowski If this answer resolved your issue, you should mark it as accepted. This helps future visitors that may be having the same issue know that this answer will likely help them as well.

Comment: It says my reputation isn't high enough to vote and publicly change the score, but I would if I could.

Comment: @BrandonLukowski There should be a checkmark you can click.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Sorry first time posting, I've got you now though!